# Copy data from local disk to hdfs in a federation of HDFS

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to configure a Federation of HDFS. Therefore, I configured the `$ cat etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml` in both hosts (hadoop-coc-1, and hadoop-coc-2).

The problem is that with this configuration, I want to copy data from local disk to HDFS but I can't.

I have tried the commands below and I get an error:

```
$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ~/input1 webhdfs://hadoop-coc-1/
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/xubuntu/Programs/hadoop-2.6.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
15/03/02 12:32:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
copyFromLocal: Connection refused

$ curl -i -X PUT -T ~/input1 "http://hadoop-coc-1:8080/?op=CREATE"
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 405 HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL
Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2015 17:34:35 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2015 17:34:35 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)

```

Any help to copy data from the local disk to HDFS? Did I configure the system properly?

hdfs-site.xml

`<configuration>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
     <value>ns1,ns2</value>
    </property>
        <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS.ns1</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoop-coc-1:9000</value>
       </property>
       <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS.ns2</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoop-coc-2:9000</value>
       </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ns1</name>
         <value>hadoop-coc-1:6600</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.ns1</name>
         <value>hadoop-coc-1:8080</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.secondaryhttp-address.ns1</name>
         <value>hadoop-coc-1:8080</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ns2</name>
         <value>hadoop-coc-2:6600</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.ns2</name>
         <value>hadoop-coc-2:8080</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.secondaryhttp-address.ns2</name>
         <value>hadoop-coc-2:8080</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
        </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.support.append</name>
     <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>`

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The HDFS service is running the port 6600.